# Process running as systemd daemon has high CPU usage

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, systemd

I have a C++ compiled executable, `program`, that can be ran as a background process via systemd.

It can also be run as a regular process through command line (used mostly for debugging).

The process does regular IO operations between other applications and an external device. The device communication happens via TCP/IP ethernet, while the application communications are all inter-process communications.

The issue is that the application, when run as a stand-alone executable run with a CPU usage of about 0.7%  - 1.3%.

When the same application is ran as a systemd background process, the CPU% usage jumps to run at about the max `CPUQuota` allowed in configurations. In this case, we have it set to 5%.

Why is this? Is there something happening in systemd causing this issue? The only difference from a code perspective between running as an application or a daemon is that when ran as a daemon we send a heart beat at sent intervals.

Comment: What happens if you run the program in daemon mode but without systemd? What results do you get from trying to trace what the program does (e.g. using strace)?

Comment: @grawity I haven't tried that yet because I didn't know that was possible. I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thanks for `strace` as well. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Apply these tweaks:

**1. Change your I/O scheduler to mq-deadline, as shown:**

Ensure that the [mq-deadline scheduler](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Multi-Queue_Block_IO_Queueing_Mechanism_(blk-mq)) is loaded on startup by adding an entry for it in `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`:

`echo mq-deadline >> /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`

Then edit `/etc/default/grub` and ensure that the multiqueue deadline scheduler is enabled:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 elevator=mq-deadline"`

When done, issue:

`sudo update-grub`

Then reboot. Note that [single queue schedulers were removed as from Linux 5.x](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f382fb0bcef4c37dc049e9f6963e3baf204d815c).

The goal of this is to ensure that CFQ (Completely Fair Queuing) is overridden.
This may be the default scheduler on your Linux distribution, though of late, the [likes of OpenSUSE](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/archive/42.3/tuning/html/book.sle.tuning/cha.tuning.io.html) have began setting the multi-queue deadline scheduler as the default.
The primary advantage of the multi queue deadline scheduler is its' very low CPU overhead.

**2. Most important:** Disable the autogroup feature (which is enabled by default) and tweak the value(s) of sched_migration_cost variable on `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Drop in these lines in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```sh
kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled=0
kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns = 5000000
```

Then run `sysctl -p` and reboot.

I ran into a similar issue a while back in production, which was fixed with the tweaks above. The explanations for the various options in [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/50E4AAB1.9040902@optionshouse.com) thread were extremely useful, as was the follow up on a [similar case with Proxmox](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/increase-performance-with-sched_autogroup_enabled-0.41729/).